# Remove Business Days from Date

Tags: apex

Did anyone try subtracting business days(excluding weekends) from a given date. The given date might also fall on a weekend.

Please let me know if anyone has implemented this.

Comment: have you looked at the business hours class? get the number of business days between two dates then subtract that from the total days between dates with give you the non business days (weekends and holidays)

Comment: Hi Eric - Do you have any code for this?